# wpdb query on custom table not working

Tags: database, sql

I want to show one custom table from my database on which WordPress is installed.
So I googled this code:

```
<?php 
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM sparte-bogensport") );
foreach ($results as $result) { 
     echo '<p>' .$result->id. '</p>';
} ?>
```

But it does not work. When I changed the table name to one word for testing, then it works:

```
<?php 
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM test") );
foreach ($results as $result) { 
     echo '<p>' .$result->tester. '</p>';
} ?>
```

Why does the `sparte-bogensport` table name doesn't work?

This query should be shown over a page. I used the plugin "PHP Code For Posts" but this don't support WordPress varaibles. Do you have an alternative for me?

Regards
Peronia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting the table name inside quotes, like this

```
SELECT * FROM `sparte-bogensport`
```

**Edit**

More info on why this happens:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Comment: make my day, works like a charm. But why? There are no spaces or something similar...

Comment: It's the "-". Don't know exactly why it breaks, but that's it's recommended to keep table tames to letters and underscores.